# Getting Mail body In PHP

Tags: php, email

**What I am doing:**

First I am trying to get email and save the reply of user in my database.
For this I am using PHP `imap` method to get mail from my email address.

**Code:**

```
function get_email()
{
    //define server, email , password
    $server    = '{server.example.com:143}INBOX';
    $user_name = 'login';
    $user_pass = 'password';

    $mail = imap_open( $server , $user_name , $user_pass );

    $headers = imap_num_msg($mail);//counting the no of msg

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $headers ; $i++) 
    { 
        $body = imap_fetchbody($mail, $i ,1);
        $body = explode(">",$body);   
        $body = $body['0'];
        $body = substr($body, 0, -5);
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "/-/-/-/-/-/".$body."/-/-/-/-/-/";
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    // close the connection
    imap_close($mail);
}
```

**Now:** 
The Result that i am getting from `$body = imap_fetchbody($mail, $i ,$i);` is this:

```
Okay What new in it.

On Thu, Feb 12, 2015 at 4:56 PM, admin  wrote:

> My name is admin!
>
>
```

but only wanted a the msg body that `Okay What new in it.` . So I `explode()` the massage and get the first element of array and remove the last line.

**Problem:**
**I could not remove last line the current result of this program Is:**

```
Okay What new in it.

On Thu, Feb 12, 2015 at 4:56 PM, admin
```

Even I have add `"/-/-/-/-/-/"` symbol but the symbol are not showing.

Comment: You cannot reliably separate the actual reply from the quoted reply, because every client is configured differently for the `"On Thu, Feb 12..."` part. Many omit it entirely, and it is user-configurable. The `>` prefix for quoted reply is not reliable in and of itself either.

Comment: Also, many people reply inline with the existing quoted reply, interleaving new message content with the relevant parts of the quoted message.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes I know that but i can't think of a reliable solution for this.

Comment: I don't think there ever will be a reliable solution for what you want to do. You can search for the block of lines beginning with `>` then back up one line to delete the date, but on some messages, the date may not be present and you would delete content. Email does not have a standardized body format.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski one more solution that i can think of is to ask user to enter a specific symbol in the end of massage but it is also not a good solution.

Comment: To put it very bluntly: the quoted original _is_ part of the body, so what you want is not "_getting_  the body of the mail" (which you have succeeded in, clearly) but _parsing_ it and - as said - doing so reliably can be a challenge.

Comment: Exploding by '>' is a pretty bad idea, what if the message has HTML? Or its simply used within the body?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not ideal, and this answer will not be ideal either. Because frankly what you are trying to accomplish can be quite difficult, because previous messages in a thread on emails will be different depending on client used and you cannot trust the user either (the thread below the 'body' could have been altered by the user etc.)

Using explode by '>' is not ideal, because what if it is part of the message?

exploding by `\n>` is a no go too because a user might inline responses as @Michael_Berkovski said.

Anyways here is my solution:

`$body = preg_replace('#(\n>.*?)+$#','',$body);`

This will reduce the following:

```
This is the body
> And this is a comment within the body
Also just the body

>Previous messages
>here
>> Even indented who cares?
```

to:

```
This is the body
> And this is a comment within the body
Also just the body
```

Comment: Also consider using an abstraction for the imap_ functionality in PHP it is really easy to get wrong, and it can really be a hassle... As shameless as I am I can only suggest that you use something like this: https://github.com/EJTH/php-mailbox-reader It handles html messages, multipart and attachments too, including inlined images. Though im pretty sure that its easy to XSS attack it, so use it with a sanitizer if you plan on allowing HTML messages.

Answer (score 0):

For trying very hard I come to a solution that ask user to reply with `'#'` at the end of the massage. As I notice there are different types of replies from different mailing services but all services show reply first.

**Code:**

```
$msgno = imap_num_msg($mail);
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $msgno ; $i++) 
  { 
    $body = imap_fetchbody($mail, $i ,1);
    $body = explode("#",$body);
    $body = $body['0'];
    echo $body;
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

From this I got my desire result.

Comment: What if a user sends an url with a hash in it? What if I say that I am #1? The # character is pretty common,...

Comment: The user can't send me email direct. He have to reply my massage.so i told user not to enter # tag in question but at the end of his answer.